# Attempt to reduce to problem of inner product

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, reductions, combinatorics, satisfiability

The problem of Orthogonality: gives $n$ vectors of dimension $k$ and another set of same, can a pair be found with inner product = $0$?

The problem of max product: likewise two sets each $n$ vectors (I forgot to mention in both cases values are binary). We want to find maximal inner product (one vector from set $A$ and one from $B$).

I want to find a reduction between OV to max. Inner product.

My idea:
Use negative values, claim its equivalent with negative value and possitive values.

What I mean, OV reduced to max. Inner prod with negative values by multiplying all by $-1$.

Then if maximum is zero... Orthogonality. Else, no orthogonality.

But i need to argue negative max inner product equivalent to max. Inner product.

Maybe there is another way?

If it does not work, also interested in reduction from sat.

Comment: What kind of reduction are you looking for? Many to one reductions? Turing reductions?

Comment: Turing reduction will be good, and if possible, many to one. But even turing will assiste me.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is to take the tensor squares of the vector: replace each vector $x$ with a new vector $\hat{x}$ given by $\hat{x}_{ij} = x_i x_j$ (the vectors have length $k^2)$.
We have
$$
\langle \hat{x}, \hat{y} \rangle =
\sum_{ij} x_i x_j y_i y_j = \langle x,y \rangle^2.
$$
Therefore if you know the *minimum* inner product, you can solve OV. It remains to negate all vectors in one of the sets.

Comment: This is interesting. But for minimum inner product, there is no need for that simply leave the vectors as they are and then if minimal ip is 0 they are orthogonal and else they are not. My problem begins when i try reducing to maximum inner product i thought they are equivalent easily, but it required more than just multiplying by $-1$ (if simply multiply by $-1$, we get also positive values when multiplied, also to note).

Comment: Use $\langle \hat x, - \hat y \rangle = -\langle x,y \rangle^2$.

Comment: Simple and brilliant.

Comment: sorry some still bugs me is that if we reduce minimal inner product to max inner product simply by negating one set, it still will not be enough, because we have (0,1)-min inner product to (0,-1)-max inner product, but i dont see a trivial reduction from (0,-1)-max inner product to (0,1)-max inner product. Sorry for mispelling.

Comment: I gave you a start. You take it from here.

Comment: hm but still for this i would not need to increase the dimension. leaving the data as is already is reduction from orthogonal to minimal value. increasing the dimension has didnt change